# ubuntu splits in 4 screens

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu desktop replacing macos but it split on 4 screens and I can't read anything [Ubuntu installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsCKO.jpg)

Comment: Which Mac are you trying to install Ubuntu on? Some of them are less straightforward than others ...

Comment: hi, late iMac 2009